# Update Foreign Key referencing to Unique Key in another table in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I've user table and orders table. UserId in orders table references to Id in users table which is UNIQUE. My requirement is that the UserId should automatically be updated whenever Id is changed.
I've tried to do this:

```
FOREIGN KEY (COLUMN_USER_ID) REFERENCES TABLE_USERS (COLUMN_ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

but apparently this doesn't work.

Comment: Did you [enable foreign keys](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onConfigure(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase))?

Comment: Yes i did enable them @CL

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "doesn't work"?

Comment: I changed ID in users table, but the user id (which is foreign key in the other table) didn't change